# Allocate two objects contiguously. Get the first one from the address of the second. After creation, don't statically know the second object's type

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-layout

I'm trying to write a factory that allocates two objects contiguously in a single block of memory. Then, given the address of the second object, I need to obtain the first one.

To further complicate things, the second object can be of any type derived from a given base class.

Here some code to show what I need:

```
// the second object in memory is always a Node
struct Node { virtual ~Node()=default; };
struct X : Node {};

struct First {}; // first object in memory

// I need to do this:
int main() {
    // factory creates and manages Nodes with an associated First object
    Factory factory;
    // creating a Node
    X* node = factory.make<X>();
    // retrieving the First object associated to node
    First* first = getFirst( node );
}
```

And here my (failed) implementation attempt.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Factory {
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<???> > memory; // what should its type be?
    
    template<typename T> T* make() {
        struct Block { First first; T second; };
        auto blockPtr = std::make_unique<Block>();
        auto& block = *blockPtr;
        memory.push_back( std::move(blockPtr) );
        return block.second;
    }
    First* getFirst( Node* node ) {
        // what do I do here?
    }
};
```

How can I implement this correctly in C++?

Any standard is fine, preferably C++17, but C++20 is OK too.

I am able to implement the behavior of Factory in other ways. For instance
by using a `std::unordered_map<Node*, First>` to associate a First to a Node. But I think it should be possible to keep the two objects in the same memory block and access them with pointer arithmetics.

Comment: The only way to guarantee two objects are adjacent in memory is to use an array/vector of objects (making they have to be the same type). A vector of pointers won't work. You'll probably have to allocate a block of memory for both objects then use placement new to create them within that block. There's probably an easier way to solve whatever you're trying to do than allocating adjacent objects

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I only need `First` and `T` to be adjacent. They can be in a structure (and thus the offset between them is constant). Different pairs of objects don't need to be adjacent in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You want to associate classes that are derived from `Node` but otherwise totally arbitrary to instances of `First` so we would need to create a templated class to keep them together:

```
template <typename T>
class Block
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Node, T>);
  First _first;
  T _instance;
};
```

Given that we do not know the alignment of `T` we cannot, in general, know the offset between `_first` and `_instance` so just using pointer arithmetic to find `&_first` from `&_instance` is not possible.
If you just want to keep them together and are ok with finding `&_first` via a lookup from an associative container, you could use something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
public:
  virtual ~Node() = default;
};

class First {};



class I_Block
{
public:
  virtual First * get_first() = 0;

  virtual ~I_Block() = default;
};


template <typename T>
class Block : public I_Block
{
public:
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Node, T>, "T must be derived from Node");

  Block()
  : _first(), _instance()
  { }

  First * get_first() override
  {
    return &_first;
  }

  T * get_instance()
  {
    return &_instance;
  }
protected:
private:
  First _first;
  T _instance;
};



class Factory
{
public:
  Factory() = default;

  template <typename T>
  T * make()
  {
    auto block = std::make_unique<Block<T>>();
    T * result = block->get_instance();
    _memory.emplace(result, std::move(block));
    return result;
  }

  First * get_first(Node const * node) const
  {
    auto block = _memory.find(node);
    if (block == _memory.end()) throw 123; // node not found
    return block->second->get_first();
  }

protected:
private:
  std::map<Node const *, std::unique_ptr<I_Block>> _memory;
};






class Alpha : public Node
{
public:
  Alpha() = default;
protected:
private:
};

class Beta : public Node
{
public:
  Beta() = default;

  virtual void doit() { }
protected:
private:
  double _value;
};



int main()
{
  Factory factory;

  Alpha * alpha = factory.make<Alpha>();
  std::cout << "&alpha = " << alpha << std::endl;
  std::cout << "&first(alpha) = " << factory.get_first(alpha) << std::endl;

  Beta * beta = factory.make<Beta>();
  std::cout << "&beta = " << beta << std::endl;
  std::cout << "&first(beta) = " << factory.get_first(beta) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "Given that we do not know the alignment of T we cannot, in general." Wouldn't it be possible to force the alignment and/or make sure that it's always the same with a static_assert?

Comment: The problem of this solution is that it's using a `std::map` to find a block given a `Node*`. That's exactly what I want to avoid. If I was OK with using a `std::map`, I wouldn't need `Block` at all: I could simply use a `std::map<Node*, First>`.